# Update query not working 7-8% of the records

Tags: mysql

I suppose this is not easy.
I have a simple update query that works fine, the problem is that 7-8% of the records are not updated. It seems the LEFT JOIN cannot always match the ON clause.

I have checked the not matched fields to see if there are some white spaces but there are none. I also checked for duplicates in the LEFT table, none also here.
Of course I've also checked that the records exist in both tables.

I'm using MySQL 8.0 under Windows 10

This is my code:

```
  UPDATE `61_LoadUnit`
    LEFT JOIN `statistics`.`tbl_g08t1`
    ON `61_LoadUnit`.`StUnit` = `statistics`.`tbl_g08t1`.`ecarrno`
    SET `61_LoadUnit`.`carrno` = `statistics`.`tbl_g08t1`.`carrno`
    WHERE `61_LoadUnit`.`carrno` IN (NULL, 0);
```

Some data for `StUnit=29318284`. Sorry, I do not know how to paste tables.

```html
61_loadunit
<html>
  <head>
    <title>61_loadunit</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="HeidiSQL 10.2.0.5599">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      thead tr {background-color: ActiveCaption; color: CaptionText;}
      th, td {vertical-align: top; font-family: "Tahoma", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px; }
      table, td {border: 1px solid silver;}
      table {border-collapse: collapse;}
      thead .col0 {width: 64px;}
      thead .col1 {width: 89px;}
      thead .col2 {width: 83px;}
      thead .col3 {width: 90px;}
      thead .col4 {width: 52px;}
      thead .col5 {width: 51px;}
      thead .col6 {width: 35px;}
      thead .col7 {width: 35px;}
      thead .col8 {width: 89px;}
      thead .col9 {width: 95px;}
      thead .col10 {width: 83px;}
      .col10 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col11 {width: 88px;}
      .col11 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col12 {width: 157px;}
      thead .col13 {width: 67px;}
      thead .col14 {width: 71px;}
      thead .col15 {width: 70px;}
      .col15 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col16 {width: 87px;}
      .col16 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col17 {width: 147px;}
      thead .col18 {width: 83px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table caption="61_loadunit (3 rows)">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col0">Division</th>
          <th class="col1">Confirmation</th>
          <th class="col2">RefID</th>
          <th class="col3">WCS_LoadId</th>
          <th class="col4">MHA</th>
          <th class="col5">Rack</th>
          <th class="col6">X</th>
          <th class="col7">Y</th>
          <th class="col8">StUnit</th>
          <th class="col9">Weight_LW61</th>
          <th class="col10">carrno</th>
          <th class="col11">Shortl62</th>
          <th class="col12">Partno</th>
          <th class="col13">PartRev</th>
          <th class="col14">DivCode</th>
          <th class="col15">Quantity</th>
          <th class="col16">partwght</th>
          <th class="col17">CreationDateTime</th>
          <th class="col18">RunDate</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">WCS1</td>
          <td class="col1">0</td>
          <td class="col2">10762181</td>
          <td class="col3">10762181</td>
          <td class="col4">ID1</td>
          <td class="col5"></td>
          <td class="col6"></td>
          <td class="col7"></td>
          <td class="col8">AKS22282</td>
          <td class="col9">482.00</td>
          <td class="col10">32614650</td>
          <td class="col11">166540</td>
          <td class="col12">RB-12.7/G16VX310A       </td>
          <td class="col13">      </td>
          <td class="col14">AKS   </td>
          <td class="col15">54000</td>
          <td class="col16">0.008454</td>
          <td class="col17">2019-08-29T14:52:09Z</td>
          <td class="col18">20190830</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">WCS1</td>
          <td class="col1">0</td>
          <td class="col2">10762178</td>
          <td class="col3">10762178</td>
          <td class="col4">ID1</td>
          <td class="col5"></td>
          <td class="col6"></td>
          <td class="col7"></td>
          <td class="col8">799197533</td>
          <td class="col9">126.20</td>
          <td class="col10">32577072</td>
          <td class="col11">223198</td>
          <td class="col12">PER.UCFX12A-A           </td>
          <td class="col13">33 47 </td>
          <td class="col14">479PBE</td>
          <td class="col15">15</td>
          <td class="col16">5.8</td>
          <td class="col17">2019-08-29T14:51:49Z</td>
          <td class="col18">20190830</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">WCS1</td>
          <td class="col1">0</td>
          <td class="col2">10762172</td>
          <td class="col3">10762172</td>
          <td class="col4">ID1</td>
          <td class="col5"></td>
          <td class="col6"></td>
          <td class="col7"></td>
          <td class="col8">29318284</td>
          <td class="col9">223.80</td>
          <td class="col10"></td>
          <td class="col11"></td>
          <td class="col12"></td>
          <td class="col13"></td>
          <td class="col14"></td>
          <td class="col15"></td>
          <td class="col16"></td>
          <td class="col17">2019-08-29T14:51:29Z</td>
          <td class="col18">20190830</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>

tbl_g08t1
<html>
  <head>
    <title>tbl_g08t1</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="HeidiSQL 10.2.0.5599">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      thead tr {background-color: ActiveCaption; color: CaptionText;}
      th, td {vertical-align: top; font-family: "Tahoma", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px; }
      table, td {border: 1px solid silver;}
      table {border-collapse: collapse;}
      thead .col0 {width: 87px;}
      .col0 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col1 {width: 91px;}
      .col1 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col2 {width: 77px;}
      .col2 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col3 {width: 69px;}
      .col3 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col4 {width: 66px;}
      .col4 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col5 {width: 74px;}
      .col5 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col6 {width: 50px;}
      .col6 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col7 {width: 71px;}
      .col7 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col8 {width: 62px;}
      .col8 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col9 {width: 46px;}
      .col9 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col10 {width: 62px;}
      .col10 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col11 {width: 64px;}
      thead .col12 {width: 54px;}
      thead .col13 {width: 65px;}
      thead .col14 {width: 65px;}
      thead .col15 {width: 56px;}
      thead .col16 {width: 63px;}
      thead .col17 {width: 70px;}
      .col17 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col18 {width: 63px;}
      .col18 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col19 {width: 62px;}
      .col19 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col20 {width: 69px;}
      .col20 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col21 {width: 87px;}
      .col21 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col22 {width: 69px;}
      .col22 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col23 {width: 93px;}
      .col23 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col24 {width: 138px;}
      thead .col25 {width: 138px;}
      thead .col26 {width: 138px;}
      thead .col27 {width: 110px;}
      thead .col28 {width: 135px;}
      thead .col29 {width: 58px;}
      .col29 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col30 {width: 62px;}
      .col30 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col31 {width: 66px;}
      .col31 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col32 {width: 56px;}
      .col32 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col33 {width: 54px;}
      .col33 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col34 {width: 58px;}
      .col34 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col35 {width: 92px;}
      thead .col36 {width: 92px;}
      thead .col37 {width: 92px;}
      thead .col38 {width: 69px;}
      .col38 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col39 {width: 108px;}
      thead .col40 {width: 60px;}
      .col40 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col41 {width: 65px;}
      .col41 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col42 {width: 71px;}
      .col42 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col43 {width: 71px;}
      .col43 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col44 {width: 73px;}
      .col44 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col45 {width: 74px;}
      .col45 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col46 {width: 54px;}
      .col46 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col47 {width: 94px;}
      thead .col48 {width: 193px;}
      thead .col49 {width: 74px;}
      .col49 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col50 {width: 83px;}
      .col50 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col51 {width: 61px;}
      .col51 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col52 {width: 71px;}
      .col52 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col53 {width: 71px;}
      .col53 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col54 {width: 138px;}
      thead .col55 {width: 138px;}
      thead .col56 {width: 63px;}
      thead .col57 {width: 76px;}
      .col57 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col58 {width: 70px;}
      .col58 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col59 {width: 70px;}
      .col59 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col60 {width: 69px;}
      .col60 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col61 {width: 66px;}
      .col61 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col62 {width: 76px;}
      .col62 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col63 {width: 71px;}
      .col63 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col64 {width: 67px;}
      .col64 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col65 {width: 67px;}
      .col65 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col66 {width: 75px;}
      .col66 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col67 {width: 140px;}
      thead .col68 {width: 57px;}
      .col68 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col69 {width: 71px;}
      .col69 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col70 {width: 69px;}
      .col70 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col71 {width: 79px;}
      thead .col72 {width: 48px;}
      thead .col73 {width: 54px;}
      thead .col74 {width: 83px;}
      thead .col75 {width: 67px;}
      thead .col76 {width: 67px;}
      thead .col77 {width: 54px;}
      thead .col78 {width: 54px;}
      thead .col79 {width: 85px;}
      thead .col80 {width: 77px;}
      thead .col81 {width: 59px;}
      thead .col82 {width: 76px;}
      thead .col83 {width: 67px;}
      thead .col84 {width: 67px;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table caption="tbl_g08t1 (3 rows)">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col0">shortl62</th>
          <th class="col1">carrno</th>
          <th class="col2">shortg04</th>
          <th class="col3">carrtype</th>
          <th class="col4">carrstat</th>
          <th class="col5">approved</th>
          <th class="col6">avail</th>
          <th class="col7">reserved</th>
          <th class="col8">carrctrl</th>
          <th class="col9">lock</th>
          <th class="col10">labeled</th>
          <th class="col11">mha</th>
          <th class="col12">rack</th>
          <th class="col13">horcoor</th>
          <th class="col14">vercoor</th>
          <th class="col15">ldct</th>
          <th class="col16">loctype</th>
          <th class="col17">stkquant</th>
          <th class="col18">stkzero</th>
          <th class="col19">delamo</th>
          <th class="col20">amooncr</th>
          <th class="col21">carrwght</th>
          <th class="col22">ldctwght</th>
          <th class="col23">carrvol</th>
          <th class="col24">regdate</th>
          <th class="col25">statdate</th>
          <th class="col26">stkdate</th>
          <th class="col27">freetxt1</th>
          <th class="col28">freetxt2</th>
          <th class="col29">minval</th>
          <th class="col30">maxval</th>
          <th class="col31">freerow</th>
          <th class="col32">depth</th>
          <th class="col33">width</th>
          <th class="col34">height</th>
          <th class="col35">bbdate</th>
          <th class="col36">ltdate</th>
          <th class="col37">lsdate</th>
          <th class="col38">lockcode</th>
          <th class="col39">allomark</th>
          <th class="col40">refg08</th>
          <th class="col41">ocarrno</th>
          <th class="col42">shortg00</th>
          <th class="col43">shortg02</th>
          <th class="col44">marktype</th>
          <th class="col45">checksum</th>
          <th class="col46">origin</th>
          <th class="col47">ecarrno</th>
          <th class="col48">g08fifo</th>
          <th class="col49">g08huqty</th>
          <th class="col50">shorto42</th>
          <th class="col51">icarrno</th>
          <th class="col52">shortg07</th>
          <th class="col53">shortg37</th>
          <th class="col54">g08pdate</th>
          <th class="col55">g08stkch</th>
          <th class="col56">origldct</th>
          <th class="col57">g08uwrap</th>
          <th class="col58">g08retur</th>
          <th class="col59">g08scale</th>
          <th class="col60">g08stort</th>
          <th class="col61">g08tqty</th>
          <th class="col62">g08badpu</th>
          <th class="col63">g08stqty</th>
          <th class="col64">firecode</th>
          <th class="col65">shortl66</th>
          <th class="col66">g08bcode</th>
          <th class="col67">ldctid</th>
          <th class="col68">ldctori</th>
          <th class="col69">g08crosc</th>
          <th class="col70">shortf04</th>
          <th class="col71">rundate</th>
          <th class="col72">txt8</th>
          <th class="col73">txt50</th>
          <th class="col74">txt71</th>
          <th class="col75">txt72</th>
          <th class="col76">txt73</th>
          <th class="col77">txt74</th>
          <th class="col78">txt75</th>
          <th class="col79">txt76</th>
          <th class="col80">txt97</th>
          <th class="col81">txt98</th>
          <th class="col82">txt132</th>
          <th class="col83">txt137</th>
          <th class="col84">txt155</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">165550</td>
          <td class="col1">33948712</td>
          <td class="col2">2249873</td>
          <td class="col3">0</td>
          <td class="col4">6</td>
          <td class="col5">1</td>
          <td class="col6">1</td>
          <td class="col7">0</td>
          <td class="col8">0</td>
          <td class="col9">0</td>
          <td class="col10">0</td>
          <td class="col11">B    </td>
          <td class="col12">011</td>
          <td class="col13">009</td>
          <td class="col14">008</td>
          <td class="col15">P01</td>
          <td class="col16">   </td>
          <td class="col17">6720</td>
          <td class="col18">0</td>
          <td class="col19">134400</td>
          <td class="col20">73600</td>
          <td class="col21">110.4</td>
          <td class="col22">0</td>
          <td class="col23">68.448</td>
          <td class="col24">2016-04-28 22:53:09</td>
          <td class="col25">2017-11-24 15:08:55</td>
          <td class="col26">2017-11-24 15:08:55</td>
          <td class="col27">                         </td>
          <td class="col28">L79CREXP                 </td>
          <td class="col29">0</td>
          <td class="col30">0</td>
          <td class="col31">7</td>
          <td class="col32">0</td>
          <td class="col33">0</td>
          <td class="col34">0</td>
          <td class="col35">                   </td>
          <td class="col36">                   </td>
          <td class="col37">                   </td>
          <td class="col38">0</td>
          <td class="col39">                    </td>
          <td class="col40">0</td>
          <td class="col41">0</td>
          <td class="col42">0</td>
          <td class="col43">0</td>
          <td class="col44">0</td>
          <td class="col45">0</td>
          <td class="col46">0</td>
          <td class="col47">J14122156</td>
          <td class="col48">0000165550.16042822:53          </td>
          <td class="col49">0</td>
          <td class="col50">0</td>
          <td class="col51">0</td>
          <td class="col52">0</td>
          <td class="col53">0</td>
          <td class="col54">2016-04-28 22:53:09</td>
          <td class="col55">2016-09-27 01:40:37</td>
          <td class="col56">   </td>
          <td class="col57">0</td>
          <td class="col58">0</td>
          <td class="col59">0</td>
          <td class="col60">0</td>
          <td class="col61">0</td>
          <td class="col62">0</td>
          <td class="col63">0</td>
          <td class="col64">0</td>
          <td class="col65">0</td>
          <td class="col66">0</td>
          <td class="col67">                                   </td>
          <td class="col68">0</td>
          <td class="col69">0</td>
          <td class="col70">0</td>
          <td class="col71">19-08-29</td>
          <td class="col72"></td>
          <td class="col73"></td>
          <td class="col74">20160427</td>
          <td class="col75">20160321</td>
          <td class="col76"></td>
          <td class="col77">J-SLS201609S</td>
          <td class="col78">03</td>
          <td class="col79">J14122156</td>
          <td class="col80"></td>
          <td class="col81"></td>
          <td class="col82">JGBR</td>
          <td class="col83"></td>
          <td class="col84"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">165551</td>
          <td class="col1">378320</td>
          <td class="col2">2401256</td>
          <td class="col3">0</td>
          <td class="col4">6</td>
          <td class="col5">1</td>
          <td class="col6">1</td>
          <td class="col7">0</td>
          <td class="col8">0</td>
          <td class="col9">0</td>
          <td class="col10">0</td>
          <td class="col11">A    </td>
          <td class="col12">011</td>
          <td class="col13">054</td>
          <td class="col14">011</td>
          <td class="col15">P01</td>
          <td class="col16">   </td>
          <td class="col17">4920</td>
          <td class="col18">0</td>
          <td class="col19">98400</td>
          <td class="col20">98400</td>
          <td class="col21">223.8</td>
          <td class="col22">0</td>
          <td class="col23">65.928</td>
          <td class="col24">2019-08-29 11:27:59</td>
          <td class="col25">2019-08-29 14:55:29</td>
          <td class="col26">2019-08-29 11:27:59</td>
          <td class="col27">                         </td>
          <td class="col28">TI39405                  </td>
          <td class="col29">0</td>
          <td class="col30">0</td>
          <td class="col31">5</td>
          <td class="col32">0</td>
          <td class="col33">0</td>
          <td class="col34">0</td>
          <td class="col35">                   </td>
          <td class="col36">                   </td>
          <td class="col37">                   </td>
          <td class="col38">0</td>
          <td class="col39">                    </td>
          <td class="col40">0</td>
          <td class="col41">0</td>
          <td class="col42">0</td>
          <td class="col43">0</td>
          <td class="col44">0</td>
          <td class="col45">0</td>
          <td class="col46">0</td>
          <td class="col47">29318284</td>
          <td class="col48">0000165551.19082911:27          </td>
          <td class="col49">0</td>
          <td class="col50">0</td>
          <td class="col51">0</td>
          <td class="col52">0</td>
          <td class="col53">0</td>
          <td class="col54">2019-08-29 11:27:59</td>
          <td class="col55">2019-08-29 11:27:59</td>
          <td class="col56">   </td>
          <td class="col57">0</td>
          <td class="col58">0</td>
          <td class="col59">0</td>
          <td class="col60">3</td>
          <td class="col61">0</td>
          <td class="col62">0</td>
          <td class="col63">0</td>
          <td class="col64">0</td>
          <td class="col65">0</td>
          <td class="col66">0</td>
          <td class="col67">                                   </td>
          <td class="col68">0</td>
          <td class="col69">0</td>
          <td class="col70">0</td>
          <td class="col71">19-08-29</td>
          <td class="col72"></td>
          <td class="col73"></td>
          <td class="col74">20190721</td>
          <td class="col75"></td>
          <td class="col76"></td>
          <td class="col77">V-SKFIT201925C</td>
          <td class="col78"></td>
          <td class="col79">J19070586</td>
          <td class="col80"></td>
          <td class="col81"></td>
          <td class="col82"></td>
          <td class="col83">29318284</td>
          <td class="col84"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">165551</td>
          <td class="col1">378344</td>
          <td class="col2">2401280</td>
          <td class="col3">0</td>
          <td class="col4">6</td>
          <td class="col5">1</td>
          <td class="col6">1</td>
          <td class="col7">0</td>
          <td class="col8">0</td>
          <td class="col9">0</td>
          <td class="col10">0</td>
          <td class="col11">A    </td>
          <td class="col12">006</td>
          <td class="col13">016</td>
          <td class="col14">018</td>
          <td class="col15">P01</td>
          <td class="col16">   </td>
          <td class="col17">5160</td>
          <td class="col18">0</td>
          <td class="col19">103200</td>
          <td class="col20">103200</td>
          <td class="col21">232.4</td>
          <td class="col22">0</td>
          <td class="col23">69.144</td>
          <td class="col24">2019-08-29 11:38:52</td>
          <td class="col25">2019-08-29 14:51:24</td>
          <td class="col26">2019-08-29 11:38:52</td>
          <td class="col27">                         </td>
          <td class="col28">TI39405                  </td>
          <td class="col29">0</td>
          <td class="col30">0</td>
          <td class="col31">4</td>
          <td class="col32">0</td>
          <td class="col33">0</td>
          <td class="col34">0</td>
          <td class="col35">                   </td>
          <td class="col36">                   </td>
          <td class="col37">                   </td>
          <td class="col38">0</td>
          <td class="col39">                    </td>
          <td class="col40">0</td>
          <td class="col41">0</td>
          <td class="col42">0</td>
          <td class="col43">0</td>
          <td class="col44">0</td>
          <td class="col45">0</td>
          <td class="col46">0</td>
          <td class="col47">29318308</td>
          <td class="col48">0000165551.19082911:38          </td>
          <td class="col49">0</td>
          <td class="col50">0</td>
          <td class="col51">0</td>
          <td class="col52">0</td>
          <td class="col53">0</td>
          <td class="col54">2019-08-29 11:38:52</td>
          <td class="col55">2019-08-29 11:38:52</td>
          <td class="col56">   </td>
          <td class="col57">0</td>
          <td class="col58">0</td>
          <td class="col59">0</td>
          <td class="col60">3</td>
          <td class="col61">0</td>
          <td class="col62">0</td>
          <td class="col63">0</td>
          <td class="col64">0</td>
          <td class="col65">0</td>
          <td class="col66">0</td>
          <td class="col67">                                   </td>
          <td class="col68">0</td>
          <td class="col69">0</td>
          <td class="col70">0</td>
          <td class="col71">19-08-29</td>
          <td class="col72"></td>
          <td class="col73"></td>
          <td class="col74">20190721</td>
          <td class="col75"></td>
          <td class="col76"></td>
          <td class="col77">V-SKFIT201925C</td>
          <td class="col78"></td>
          <td class="col79">J19070585</td>
          <td class="col80"></td>
          <td class="col81"></td>
          <td class="col82"></td>
          <td class="col83">29318308</td>
          <td class="col84"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot imagine a left join is useful here - do you really want to update 61_loadunit if no match is found in statistics? and I don't think in(null is helpful either - since null is never = null. sample data would help.

Comment: ok, I'll gather some examples

Comment: WHERE `61_LoadUnit`.`carrno` = 0 or `61_LoadUnit`.`carrno`is null may be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`left join` returns all rows from the left table and matching rows from the right table For this reason all records got updated from the left side of the table irrespectively...

Use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` and it will match data from both the tables and table will get updated accordingly for matched records:

```
UPDATE `61_LoadUnit`
    INNER JOIN `statistics`.`tbl_g08t1`
    ON `61_LoadUnit`.`StUnit` = `statistics`.`tbl_g08t1`.`ecarrno`
    SET `61_LoadUnit`.`carrno` = `statistics`.`tbl_g08t1`.`carrno`
    WHERE `61_LoadUnit`.`carrno` IN (NULL, 0);
```

Comment: *For this reason only those records got updated which matched from the left side of the table...* this is wrong. All rows of the left table will be updated even if they don't match. But even if it was correct (which is not) why do you propose an INNER JOIN which will do what you thought that the LEFT JOIN does?

Comment: First I changed the `WHERE` clause as you suggested, but no good result. Then I changed the JOIN from `LEFT` to `INNER` and that seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: But I quite don't get the point. The involved record with `NULL` carrno is 29318284, and if you check it is available in both tables.

Comment: @emare I guess this is not the answer where you should post the comments. Also if you have sample data post them in text tabular form so they are readable.

Comment: @forpas i think emare want to update the record which are matched in both the table thats why INNER JOIN works

Comment: @forpas u r getting rude without any reason and as menioned by emare its working for him ...so whats wrong in the answer ? I agree to the point which i mentioned only records matching from left hand side gets updated is not correct but the answer i suggest is correct

Comment: @both I'm posting here because this is the first answer with `INNER JOIN`

Comment: as suggested by emare your where clause condition itself is not correct and it also doesnt works for him...so who is wrong ?

Comment: @forpas you answer is formally the most correct, but Andrew was first with the INNER JOIN. And  P.Salmon was the first to point out that the WHERE clause was not properly working. I think there is not a *wrong code* as I have been running it for a while, it gives no error. Just recently I started to notice an increase of NULL values. To cut it short I'm marking Andrew's one

Comment: @emare *Andrew was first with the INNER JOIN* did you check the timestamps of the answers? I posted 5 mins before and my answer proposed INNER join.

Answer (score 1):

A `left join` is used to return all the rows of the *left* table even if there is no match with the joined table.
In your case if there is mo match then `statistics.tbl_g08t1.carrno` will be `null` so the column `61_LoadUnit.carrno` will be updated to `null`, but I see in the `where` clause that you want to update this column when it is `null` (or 0). 
Also this `in (null, 0)` will never succeed if the column is `null` because any comparison to `null` returns `null` and is never `true`.
So what is the point of the `left join`?
Make it an `INNER JOIN` and use the correct syntax in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE `61_LoadUnit`
INNER JOIN `statistics`.`tbl_g08t1`
ON `61_LoadUnit`.`StUnit` = `statistics`.`tbl_g08t1`.`ecarrno`
SET `61_LoadUnit`.`carrno` = `statistics`.`tbl_g08t1`.`carrno`
WHERE `61_LoadUnit`.`carrno` IS NULL OR `61_LoadUnit`.`carrno` = 0
```

or

```
WHERE COALESCE(`61_LoadUnit`.`carrno`, 0) = 0
```